# Custom ListTile inherit theme

Tags: flutter

I need to inherit the theme on my custom ListTile.

I have created a custom ListTile without inherit from it, just a statefull series of widget. How can I make this inherit all the theme from ListTile?

Normally I will normally achieve this going on single widget and setting a specific value to `Theme.of(context).whateverTheme.whateverValue`. Until now worked flowless but now I see that there is not a `.ListViewTheme` or `.ListTileTheme` to use even if list_tile.dart have it. It is probably not exposed.

This make me question myself if this is the right way to do this.

Look for the `<= I want here` in the code

```
class CustomMenuTile extends StatefulWidget {
  CustomMenuTile({Key key, this.selected, this.icon, this.text, this.routePage})
      : super(key: key);

  final bool selected;
  final IconData icon;
  final String text;
  final Widget routePage;

  @override
  _CustomMenuTileState createState() => _CustomMenuTileState();
}

class _CustomMenuTileState extends State<CustomMenuTile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
      constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(height: 48),
      child: Material(
        color: widget.selected ? kPrimarySwatch[400].withAlpha(100) : null,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
        child: InkWell(
            splashColor: Colors.grey.withAlpha(64),
            highlightColor: Colors.grey.withAlpha(64),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 24),
                      child: Icon(widget.icon,
                        color: widget.selected
                            ? Theme.of(context).accentColor
                            : null, <= I want here Theme.of(context).ListViewTheme.iconColor
                      )),
                  Text(widget.text,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: widget.selected
                              ? Theme.of(context).accentColor
                              : null)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.of(context)
                  .pushReplacement(_createFadeRoute(widget.routePage));
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ListTileTheme.of(context).textColor` or whatever property of `ListTileTheme`.

If the app doesn't define a `ListTileTheme`, all the properties returns `null`. In that case, `ListTile` define it's own values. You could look at the default values of `ListTile` and use that if a property of `ListTileTheme` is `null`

Comment: Seems the right answer but using ListTileTheme.of(context).iconColor doesn't paint the icon in grey as expected. I have 2 tile in my menu. 1 custom and 1 ListTile standard. The latter is grey the custom is not even with ListTileTheme.of(context).iconColor.
How can this be possible? Where ListTile take that value?

Comment: Watching the variable ListTileTheme.of(context) I see that all the element inside is set to null or false.

Comment: I updated my answer, because if you don't define a ListTileTheme all the properties are null.

Answer (score 0):

I think `null` does use the default. You may be looking for the `textTheme` property.

```
                Text(widget.text,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: widget.selected
                          ? Theme.of(context).accentColor
                          : Theme.of(context).textTheme.body.color),
```

Comment: yes null will use the default one but because my Custom Tile isn't actually a Tile it will use a default textTheme.
In my example i want the icon to use the default ListTile color that is grey but I don't want to change the color of all the icon in my app. It's just not right to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Looking inside the list_tile.dart seems that the color is taking the color from the ListTileTheme but as soon as you don't wrap al your code in a ListTileTheme widget the app is behaving like it doesn't have one which in fact is true.

In this case so it just go for the hardcoded color Colors.black45 but this happen just for the icon of the ListTile not the normal Icon widget.

```
Color _iconColor(ThemeData theme, ListTileTheme tileTheme) {
    if (!enabled)
      return theme.disabledColor;

    if (selected && tileTheme?.selectedColor != null)
      return tileTheme.selectedColor;

    if (!selected && tileTheme?.iconColor != null)
      return tileTheme.iconColor;

    switch (theme.brightness) {
      case Brightness.light:
        return selected ? theme.primaryColor : Colors.black45;
      case Brightness.dark:
        return selected ? theme.accentColor : null; // null - use current icon theme color
    }
    assert(theme.brightness != null);
    return null;
}
```

There is an open issue on github about the missing TileListTheme on ThemeData. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31247

---

Here a complete example of the workaround:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTileTheme(
      iconColor: Colors.blue,
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("ListTileTheme example"),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            title: Text("ListTile IS inheriting the color"),
            leading: Icon(Icons.list),
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.list),
              Text("Other Icon is NOT inheriting the color..."),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.list, color: ListTileTheme.of(context).iconColor),
              Text("...unless you use ListTileTheme.of(context).iconColor"),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This code will generate this result:

[image: Workaround example]